# $f'(a) \neq 0$. Can we say anything about the differentiability of the function on a neighbourhood around the point $x=a$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

$f(x)$ is a differentiable at the point $x=a$ and $f'(a) \neq 0$. Can we say anything about the differentiability  of the function on a neighbourhood around the point $x=a$.

I was thinking about the  function $f(x) = x^2 D(x)$. Here $D(x)$ is the Dirichilet function.
We know this function is differentiable only at $x=0$ , but $f'(0) = 0$ in this case.

Comment: With your above function $f$, doesn't defining $g$ such that $g(x) = x + f(x)$ demonstrate a function differentiable at only one point with nonzero derivative?

Comment: @Lemmon that should be an answer

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your counterexample for $f'(a) = 0$ also works for $f'(a) \neq 0$. Taking your function $f$ such that $f(x) = x^2D(x)$, we can construct $g$ such that $g(x) = x + f(x)$.

$g$ is differentiable only at $a = 0$, with derivative $g'(0)=1$.